# Put all objects of a class in a list

Tags: c#, list

I have a class in c#, called C. While I execute the program, I create new obejcts of this class. At some point, I need to create a list `List<C> listC = new List();` where I put all the objects I created.
Of course I could do this using list.Add for each object after creating this object. But for some reason that is difficult to explain, I'd rather like to add just all the objects that have ever been created of thiiss class to the list.

Is this somehow possible? I'm not sure whether there is a solution at all :-).

Thanks in advance to everyone who answers.

Comment: And what about instances that go out of scope (Garbage collection) ?

Comment: On construction, add this to an inner list

Comment: I would add it in the constructor and remove it from the list in finalize or what the functional equivalent in c# is called.

Comment: @dutt: There never will be a call to the finalizer as long as it is in the list.

Comment: The idea with the constructor sounds good, but how do I do that. At the moment, my constructor needs to strings and one bool, thus looks something like: public C (String s, string t, bool b); how can I make the object being added to the list there?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Ah yes of course, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is called the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). You use a class to construct your class and track what was constructed.

```
public class CFactory
{
    public CFactory()
    {
        CreatedCBacking = new List<C>();
    }

    private List<C> CreatedCBacking;

    public IList<C> CreatedC
    {
        get
        {
             return CreatedCBacking.AsReadonly();
        }
    }

    public C NewC(String s, string t, bool b)
    {
       C temp = new C(s, t, b);
       CreatedCBacking.Add(temp);
       return temp;
    }

}

public class C
{
     public C(String s, string t, bool b)
     {
         //You class here
     }
}
```

the way you use this is like this

```
public static void Main()
{
    var factory = new CFactory();
    var c1 = factory.NewC("string", "string", true);
    var c2 = factory.NewC("string2", "string2", false);

    foreach(var c in factory.CreatedC)
    {
        //loops over c1 and c2
    }
}
```

Comment: This has the same problem Henk mentioned in his answer: No instance of `C` will ever be garbage collected as long as it is in this list.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth That would be true if I where using a singleton or static class for the factory. However, because you must create a instance of the factory and it's internal list is not static, when the factory gets garbage collected so will the items in the internal lists (if all other references are released)

Comment: Sure. But that's not the point. You have an all-or-nothing scenario here. Either all instances created by a certain factory instance get collected or none. That may be even what the OP wants, so it isn't necessarily bad. But I find it should be explicitly pointed out, hence my comment.

Comment: True, if the factory is not longer lived as the lists it's not a problem. I am using this exact pattern my self for objects that I need reporting progress to a GUI. The factory reports the total aggregate progress from all the child objects to one progress bar, when I don't need them any more (the progress I was waiting on completes) I dispose of my factory and any underlying child objects.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth BTW, I am not disagreeing with you, I am trying to clarify for other readers who come in the future by showing a good use case where all-or-nothing is useful. But it is not needed in every situation.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth you can use [WeakReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404247(v=vs.110).aspx) in that factory to store created instances. and don't forget checking for null and remove garbage collected entries from list.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add directly to the list when you create the object, for example:

```
List<C> list = new List<C>();

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list.Add(new C());
}
```

Or you could pass the list to the class and have it add itself:

```
List<C> list = new List<C>();

public class C
{

    public C(List<C> list)
    {
        list.Add(this);
    }

}
```

You could get away without passing the list if you made it static.

Answer (score 0):

An approach to that problem could be like that:
It would be impossible to "find" all the objects of a specific type, what you could do is to build and maintain this list from the beginning. You can do that by creating a "factory" method which creates a new `c` object, add it to the spoken list, and return a reference of it. The "factory" function and the list could (and maybe should) be singletons, depends on how you gonna use it.