# Generate a list of all objects of a class

Tags: c#, list, object

I'm very green and struggling with what is either a simple concept or bad ideas from myself. With the situation like below, I've created two objects BAnimal and added them to a list BAnimalL.

```
var FennecFox = new BAnimal("Fennec Fox", "FennecFox");
var Cat = new BAnimal("Cat", "Cat");
    
BAnimalL.Add(FennecFox);
BAnimalL.Add(Cat);
```

Which is fine, and I've seen the alternative methods and can read up on those as required to make it less clunky. What I can't find an answer for is: is it possible to generate a list of all objects of a particular class? I'm working with a computer game which has these built in for some classes, but I'd imagine there's a way outside of that also.

Related: This sort of thing, without assigning an object name:

new BAnimal("Badger", "Badger");

Is it possible to do anything with this? The debugger suggested I add a discard signifier to it.

As is clear, I was thinking I could create these objects then create a list of all. Thank you if you can help; no advice is too simple.

Comment: You can do `BAnimalL.Add(new BAnimal("Fennec Fox", "FennecFox"));` and `BAnimalL.Add(new BAnimal("Cat", "Cat"))`;

Comment: Thank you, I've been playing with that too. I haven't quite grasped the significance or otherwise of it not having a (name or index or reference?) = FennecFox. That means that I can reference to it like

BAnimalL.Add(FennecFox);

The only difference to the one that the compiler wants to add to the discard is that it is in a list. Does that stop it getting trashed? Is that ok as best practise, either with a reference name or in a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class can have a contructor, and static members. An easy solution would be:

```
class BAnimal
{
   static List<BAnimal> allInstances = new();
   
   public BAnimal(string s, string t) 
   {    
      ... // initialize
      allInstances.Add(this);
   }

}
```

But I'd like to warn you that this is not a good idea in general. It is not the responsibility of a class to track its instances.

You would normally have a Game (or Zoo) object that creates, tracks and removes the other objects.

Comment: you may simply undelete your (nearly identical) answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939397/put-all-objects-of-a-class-in-a-list  :)

Comment: Thank you. I guess the answer is "best practise makes it not necessary, so it doesn't exist". An object that does this when they are created makes sense.

Which is indeed what there is for the external data (to my project) with the game I'm working with.